# How to estimate the optimal fee for transaction(Segwit addresses)?

Tags: transactions, segregated-witness

I am using Segwit addresses to create transactions. As per my knowledge usage of segwit addresses allows the transactions to process fast with fewer fees as it occupies less space in the block. Could anyone explain how to calculate the fee for transactions using segwit transactions?

Comment: Sameer, I added a link to your question. As your question is very generic, that should be it. If your question goes deeper, please show us what you have done so far, and where you got stuck. You can edit your question at any time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Legacy input size: 148 bytes (compressed)
- Legacy output size: 34 bytes (compressed)
- Segwit input size: 104 bytes
- Segwit output size: 32 bytes

so if your transaction has two inputs and one output total size is ~ 246 Bytes, Don't forget about some more additional bytes for transaction header.